# Boolean Algebra Rule 10

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

Hi I have a question about the following algebra rule

*A + AB = A*

My textbook explains this as follows
*A + AB = A*
This rule can be proved as such:

- **Step 1:**

  **Dustributive Law:**

  A + AB = A*1 = A(1+B) ***Huh...? Where do they get the one(1) from?***
- **Step 2:**

  *1 + B = 1*
- **Step 3:**

: *A + 1 = A*

Thus
*A + AB = A*

If anyone can clarify this for me it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, and as such probably would be a better fit on Maths SE.

Answer (score 2):

The 1 would stand for ⊤ or true. To prove the rule they're assuming the right side is true, distributing this information into the left side, and reducing.

Starting with A ∨ (A ∧ B) ↔ A,

`A + AB = A`

Call A ⊤,

⊤ ∨ (⊤ ∧ B) ↔ ⊤

`1 + 1 * B = 1` now it reads "true or true and B equals true" which could just as easily be "with gravy or gravy and something else, you will have gravy"

`1 + B = 1` AND having higher precedence...

`1 = 1` OR is true if at least one operand is true

`A` no further reduction possible.

It could just as easily be done using ⊥ (false) instead

⊥ ∨ (⊥ ∧ B) ↔ ⊥

`0 + 0 * B = 0` which would read "false or false and B equals false" which could just as easily be "without bananas or bananas and something else, you will not have bananas"

`0 + 0 = 0` AND having higher precedence...

`0 = 0` OR is false

`A` no further reduction possible

It might help to construct a truth table and then review the [rules for distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property). The 1 appearing in your formula is distributed into the terms to facilitate simplifying the statement.

Since rule 0101 (10) maps to (P ∧ Q) ∨ Q ↔ Q

```
P Q x
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 1
```

or a Karnaugh map

```
   ~Q Q
~P 0  1
 P 0  1
```

see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function#Table_of_binary_truth_functions : Proposition Q

Answer (score 0):

- A = A*1 (A AND TRUE has the same truth value as A, by the law of identity for AND)
- 1 = 1+B (TRUE OR B is TRUE, by the identity for OR)

So you can always replace X with X*1, and you can always replace 1 with X+1.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra